# Regular expression gets 3 words near each other. How to get their context?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
text = "I love jam. I like all other kinds of confectionery as well--cakes and croissants and things. Bagels too! Carbs for the win I say. And my other favorite kinds of food are mostly bread based - bread itself, so many different kinds of bread. I love the ones with herbs and cheese in it. I like pizza as well, and garlic bread. But most of all, jam."
```

Now, I want to identify where 3 words, "jam", "pizza" and "garlic" are near each other. So I use this regular expression:

```
fav_food = re.findall(r"\b(?:(?:((?i)pizza|pasta)|((?i)mint|garlic)|((?i)jam|jelly)|(?(1)|(?(2)|(?(3)|(?!))))\w+)\b\W*?){3,25}(?(1)(?(2)(?(3)|(?!))|(?!))|(?!))", text)
```

This gives the following output:

```
[('pizza', 'garlic', 'jam')]
```

Now,  what I need is the part of the text where these words are close to each other. I tried tokenizing the text, and iterating over the list to see if the word is in each sentence, and printing that, but that catches the errant "jam" in the beginning of the text. That's not what I need - I need only the bit of the text which contains all the 3 words close to each other.

Once the 3 words have been found in proximity in the text, is there some way of getting say 10 words before and 10 words after? Or how can I get the sentences which contain these words, (without getting sentences that contain them but are not relevant, such as the first sentence in this text)?

Comment: What do you ,mean by errant jam? What's your expected output?

Comment: Hi, I meant the "jam" in the first sentence of the text. If I did 

`for sent in sents:
    for item in fav_food:
        if item in sent:
            print sent `

it would catch the first sentence as well. 

The expected output of fav_food is what it gives but I'm looking for a way to get the context of the 3 selected words from the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a problem like this you need to ensure that you have the 3 words in your match and it should be the minimum length.For first part of our problem we need a pattern that match any combination of our words and other words, also it must be contain of all words, so you can not do something like :

```
(pizza|garlic|jam).*?(pizza|garlic|jam).*?(pizza|garlic|jam)
```

Because it will match something like `jam ...pizza...jam`.You need to create all the possibilities for your regex that it could be done with `itertools.permutations`,so you must select one of the following cases :

```
(pizza.*?garlic.*?jam)|(pizza.*?jam.*?garlic)|(garlic.*?pizza.*?jam)|(garlic.*?jam.*?pizza)|(jam.*?pizza.*?garlic)|(jam.*?garlic.*?pizza)
```

*Note* that in the preceding groups as you want the minimum match so certainly you must have one of your words in leading and one in trailing of the sentence (because if you have another words surely its redundant consider (`this is jam and pizza and garlic`) in this sentence `this is` is redundant) so here we create all the possibilities to **optimize our regex to refuse from extra searches** :

```
>>> l=('pizza', 'garlic', 'jam')
>>> p=[]
>>> for i,j,k in permutations(l,3) :
...     m=re.search(r'({}.*?{}.*?{})'.format(i,j,k),text)
...     if m :
...        p.append(m.group(0))
... 
>>> print min(p,key=len)
pizza as well, and garlic bread. But most of all, jam
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Kasra. Could you explain this part further, please? I'm not sure I understand. "Note that in the preceding groups as you want the minimum match so definitely you must have one of your words on leading and trailing of the sentence (because if you have another words surely its redundant)" 

Thanks again!

Comment: @cydb you're welcome! it fixed! also if you found this answer helpful you can tell this to community with voting and accept! l;)